# Converting VbSCript Simple Function (UCase,Left,Instr) to C# function

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have got below function in VBSCript. How can this be writtern in C#.

```
Dim Title 'As String
Function getNavID(Title)
         getNavID=UCase(Left(Title, InStr(Title, ". ") -1))
End Function
```

Comment: -1: Shown [no effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758247/how-to-write-strip-html-tags-function-in-c-sharp) to [learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752840/converting-vbscript-functions-right-len-isnumeric-cint-in-c-sharp) on your own first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string getNavID(string Title)
{
    var index = Title.IndexOf(". ");
    return Title.Substring(0, index -1).ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string getNavID(string Title)
{
    int a = Title.IndexOf('.');
    if (a >= 0) Title = Title.Substring(0, a - 1);
    return Title.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: @Manu: my code checks if that '.' char is really present, just in case it was missing...