# How to write "Strip HTML Tags" function in C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

I got below StripHTMLTags function code which work fine in VBSCript, now I want same function to be written C#

```
Function StripHTMLTags(ByVal sHTML)
    Dim objRegExp, sOutput

    sHTML = Replace(Replace(Trim(sHTML & ""), "&lt;", "<"), "&gt;", ">") ' ** PREVENT NULL ERRORS **
    If Len(sHTML) > 0 Then
        Set objRegExp = New RegExp
        With objRegExp
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Global = True
   .Pattern= "<[^>]+>"
            ' ** REPLACE ALL HTML TAG MATCHES WITH THE EMPTY STRING **
            sOutput = .Replace(sHTML, "")
        End With
        Set objRegExp = Nothing
        StripHTMLTags = sOutput
    Else
        StripHTMLTags = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Please suggest as it is really confusing me.

Comment: Have you tried? What problems did you get?

Comment: I am looking to have good regular expression which take html string as input will give stripeed html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags). @christofr, not searching, obviously. :)

Comment: @bzlm - ah, found the same post you did, before I saw your comment. :-)

Comment: When is such a function useful? Why not just html-encode the text on output?

Comment: @Manu: -1: Please do not use Stack Overflow as a [Rent-a-coder](http://www.vworker.com/?blnDidRacRedirectToVworker_RequestParm=true) tool. We like helping people, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752509/converting-vbscript-simple-function-ucase-left-instr-to-c-sharp-function) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752840/converting-vbscript-functions-right-len-isnumeric-cint-in-c-sharp) is just abusing our good-natured friendliness. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried *Regex.Replace*?

Example:

```
    static string stripHTMLTags1(string html)
    {
        string pattern = @"<[^>]+>";
        var expression = new Regex(pattern);

        return expression.Replace(html, String.Empty);
    }

    static string stripHTMLTags2(string html)
    {
        // From http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
        string pattern = @"</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:"".*?""|'.*?'|[^'"">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>";
        var expression = new Regex(pattern);

        return expression.Replace(html, String.Empty);
    }
```

[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here are regular expressions](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm) to strip tags from HTML input:

Also see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags) which goes into more detail about using C# to strip HTML tags.

Chris.